# Communicating between and android and a serial device via usb

Tags: android, serial-port, usb

I have been doing a lot of reading and searching of where to start, I have seen that some people have accomplished it.

1. Can i do this? can i plug in a cable from my android tablet and into a hardware devices serial port (with a usb to serial converter) ?
2. Can i do it without rooting the device?
3. If i can do it what are the steps that i have to do?

Does androids have an api to access the serial port on its usb ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html maybe that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished this on my rooted Nexus 7 and with the help of this API: http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/
It took me a bit of time to build my own app with api. but it also comes with already working app (incl source code).

Comment: Good day, You say that you got your app working with it.  I just want to ask a few things. If you rooted it does that mean your code is device specific to a nexus 7 ?

Comment: I have also downloaded the same code, and my android device is not rooted. This code is always displaying 0 device found.